# Push to an array from within a method in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking to push to an array from within a method in Vue.js 2, Vue is being used within Laravel and I am getting the following response. Could there be a better way of doing it?

> Uncaught TypeError: _vm.createSelection is not a function

What I wish to create is:

```
selection[
{food: Chicken, quantity: 3},
{food: Rice, quantity: 2},
{food: Pasta, quantity: 1}
];
```

The following code is being used:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Credits carried through: {{ credits }}</div>
    <div v-for="meal in meals">
      {{meal}}
      <input :id="meal" :name="meal" v-model.number="creditsPerMeal[meal]" type="number" v-on:input="createSelection()">
    </div>
    <div>
      Credits used: {{creditsSum}}/{{credits}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component ready.');

        console.log(JSON.parse(this.f));

    },

    props: ['f','c'],

    name: 'credits',
    data: function () {
     var meals = JSON.parse(this.f)

     var creditsPerMeal = {}
     for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
       creditsPerMeal[meals[i]] = 0
     }

     var createSelection = []


      return {
        credits: this.c,
        meals,
        createSelection: [],
        creditsPerMeal
      }
    },
    computed: {
      creditsSum () {
        return Object.values(this.creditsPerMeal).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      },
    },
    methods: {
       createSelection (){
           for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
               createSelection.push({
                  food: meals[i],
                  quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
               })
           }
       }
     }
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATED METHOD**

```
methods: {
   createSelection (){
       for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(this.f).length; i++) {
           this.createSelection.push({
              food: JSON.parse(this.f)[i],
              quantity: creditsPerMeal[JSON.parse(this.f)[i]]
           })
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: as a guess: `this.data.createSelection.push(...)`? How would you except the method `createSelection` to access a local variable from a different function scope?

Comment: No luck unfortunately @BalázsÉdes, I am really struggling with it. Almost need to create some kind of bind. I cant think of another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` method is creating an array property called `createSelection`, which is likely shadowing/replacing the `createSelection` *method* you're defining. Make sure you're using unique names for all members.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that has made it closer but there is still an issue padding creditsPerMeal. Im getting the following error. Uncaught ReferenceError: creditsPerMeal is not defined. Is there a way to pass this? It could be the value of the input. Could that work?

Comment: In fact that would make them all the same?

Comment: Im still getting an error, Uncaught TypeError: _vm.createSelection is not a function

Comment: Did you undo `createSelection` not being replaced with the array?

Comment: I Have tried with an without, without the original createSelection I get this error message "this$1.createSelection.push is not a function".

Comment: Then you have to change `createSelection.push` to use the right variable name. Do you see the issue? You cannot have two things with the same name. You can't have `createSelection` as both a function and an array. You need the method to be called one thing, and the array to be named another thing. And then you have to use the right name when wanting the method or the array.